# Displaying a custom line over view

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hi I want to show a line in over view like given image.

[image]

But when i am doing this i m getting line in complete view .

My code-

```
UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2,30, _MovetoSearch.frame.size.width, 1)];
lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[_MovetoSearch addSubview:lineView];
```

How to make line like above image ?

Comment: Not getting?what was the problem are you facing?

Comment: "want to show a line in over view", which view?

Comment: @Neon Samuel how to make line like above image

Comment: what is `_MovetoSearch` and have you included search icon image in `_MovetoSearch` view?

Comment: @Sujay move to search is instance of uiview

Comment: Here is the library https://github.com/mbigatti/MaterialDesignTest for material design of UItextfield @NSArray.

Answer (score 0):

When you set child view frame that time always set it using parent view frame so if in future you can change parent frame then no need to change child frame its automatically change as per parent view like I write as follow.

```
UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(_MovetoSearch.frame.origin.x+2,_MovetoSearch.frame.size.height-5, _MovetoSearch.frame.size.width-30, 1)];
    lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [_MovetoSearch addSubview:lineView];
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `searchBtn` is having similar kind of code

```
UIButton *searchBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[searchBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(_MovetoSearch.frame.size.width-32, 0, 32, 32)];    
[searchBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[searchBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"search.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[searchBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(searchBtnPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

<strike>For your `UITextField` should be</strike>

```
CGFloat fieldHeight = searchBtn.frame.size.height-2;
CGFloat fieldWidth = _MovetoSearch.frame.size.width - (searchBtn.frame.size.width + 4);

UITextField *textfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 0, fieldWidth, fieldHeight)];
[textfield setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[textfield setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleNone];
[textfield setNeedsDisplay];
[_MovetoSearch addSubview:textfield];
```

for line view

```
CGFloat fieldHeight = searchBtn.frame.size.height-2;
CGFloat fieldWidth = _MovetoSearch.frame.size.width - (searchBtn.frame.size.width + 4);

UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, fieldHeight+1, fieldWidth, 1)];
lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

[_MovetoSearch addSubview:lineView];
```

Hope it will work for you

Comment: hi  could u tell me how ur answer fit for my question ur r saying different  things textfield line and button but i want a line over unbutton or uiview and display along with it in image . if u right how could i use ur code

Comment: it is just a design  i just want ed to pass action top other view. i want to design same like above

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use layer for such task and not overuse UIView.

```
CALayer * lineLayer = [CALayer alloc]init];
[lineLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,1)];
[lineLayer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:lineLayer];
```